# Proof of ISP use for a specific period

Tags: windows, networking, connection

I need to prove I was using my ISP at a certain period: Last year from Feb 2011 to Aug 2011. Is there any log on my PC ?

Comment: When you contacted Customer Support at your ISP and asked for those records, what did they say?

Comment: Well it is them I am having to show I was using their services. It's like the first of my 6 months Internet use never existed and when I moved out I threw away my ex bills and contracts. I am in Thailand I signed two consecutive 6 months contracts. Now they are saying I only ever had one that started the last 6 months for one year and they ask me to pay 6 months extra of internet to honor the 12 months. They say they have no record of my first 6 months internet use with them

Comment: How did you pay for this service for the past year?

Comment: I received bills that I took to the 7/11 to pay. I unfortunately got rid of all those bills and contract when I moved house. So I have no proof and they say they have no record of a previous contract, nor could they find any bills for that period.

Comment: If you signed a second six month contract that also required you to maintain service for 12 months, then you extended your 12 month requirement. Even if you had that first contract, your second contract would still require you to have 12 months of service from the date it took effect.

Comment: @David: If the contract required her to maintain service for 12 months, it wouldn't be a "six month contract", according to the usual meaning of the words.

Comment: @BenVoigt: When people say they signed a "six month contract" they usually mean the signed a contract to *provide* service for a particular length of time. That can often be less than the time you agree to retain service or pay a penalty. If you don't renew the contract, you pay a penalty. Otherwise, the service requirement would be redundant -- you already agreed to the service anyway. (And this is the only way to make sense of this question. Otherwise, if the first contract didn't exist, the OP's obligation to retain service would have terminate when the second contract terminated.)

Comment: @David: The way I read it, they have two signed contracts on file, for 6 months each.  So she has to prove that she's paid for 12 months total of service.  I would never call a contract that charged an ETF in the first 12 months a "six month contract".

Comment: @BenVoigt: Then the disagreement would be over whether the last contract she signed was for six months or for a year. If that's the case, she should demand they produce the signed contract.

Answer (score 4):

E-mails you received, or sent to other people, will contain the IP address of your ISP's e-mail server, proving that they passed through the ISP's network.  And for e-mails you sent, they will contain the IP address that was temporarily issued to you, which will be part of the block controlled by your ISP.

To see this information you need to inspect the MIME headers.

---

Also, if you used an online financial site, such as online banking, it is likely that the web server recorded your IP address.

---

In the end, your computer is the last place you should look for evidence, because it's under your control and might be tampered with.  IP address logs in the hands of other companies are much more believable.

Comment: Here is the MIME of one of my email, I see the sender's IP but not mine Where can I see the ISP email server ?                     Received: from vps.delpino.net ([64.131.75.78]) by SNT0-MC1-F43.Snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
  Fri, 29 Jun 2012 16:31:10 -0700

  s=default; d=thai-flashcards.com;
  
  h=Received:Date:Message-ID:To:Subject:X-PHP-Originating-Script:From:Reply-To:Precedence:Auto-Submitted:MIME-Version:Content-Type;

Message-ID: <20120629233018.9809.qmail@vps.delpino.net>
To: aneliane@hotmail.com

Comment: @Anne: It would have to be an email you sent. Not an email you had some other service (such as Hotmail) send for you.

Comment: Oh You mean I would have had to use the mail service provided by my ISP ? I did not unfortunately ... Any other options ?

Comment: X-Originating-IP: [124.122.203.84]
From: Anne Tehemara <aneliane@hotmail.com>
To: <tak_achan@hotmail.com>
Subject: your condo
Date: Sat, 4 Jun 2011 11:35:30 +0000
Importance: Normal
MIME-Version: 1.0

Comment: Above here is an email I sent with hotmail, it has my IP and when I looked it up, it gave their server's name : asianet.co.th. Would that be an evidence ?

Comment: @Anne: Although not the best evidence (it could be faked), it is proof that you were using that ISP in June 2011.

Comment: I have quite a lot of emails with that same IP, I am going to print them and bring them to my ISP and see what they say, unless someone has a better idea, this is all I have for now. Thank you very much Ben & David for your very useful answers ! :)

Comment: @Anne: I did add some other ideas to my answer.  In any case, good luck!

Comment: @Ben regarding online banking, how do I get about to get my old IP recorded from them ? Thank you very much for this suggestion

Comment: @Anne: You'd have to contact the web server / online security group at your bank, and ask if they kept records of IP addresses that accessed your account.  Don't be surprised if they say "yes, but there's a research fee to collect them for you" though.